# Comparing columns in tab delim files

Tags: r, memory-management, csv

I have tab delimited text files. Each file has three columns -`ProbeID`, `Avgsignalintenities`, `Pvalue`. Before further analysis, I want to ensure that the data in the `ProbeID` column are correct. The `ProbeID` column in each file contains approximately 47,315 values and so I'm concerned about performance. I've included a screen shot of a single file opened in Excel. Valid files should have only 47,234 ProbeIDs.

If you want more information I can provide you immediately.

I have given the minimal information in r code.I have 4 files in which file1 is length 10 while the others are 7,I want pass all these files together into a function and check whether all of them are same length or not..if not It should return a message that the a particular file(ie file 1) is not of equal length

```
file1=list(ProbeID=c(360450,1690139,5420594,3060411,450341,5420324,730162,4200739,1090156,7050341),X1234Avgintensity=c(110.3703,469.5097,407.557,123.9965   ,2234.529,190.7429,110.072,314.7892,153.486,160.4385),X1234Pvalue=c(0.8424522,0.01054713,0.01450231,0.5800923,0,0.1437047,0.8477257,0.02900461,0.286091,0.2406065))

file2=list(ProbeID=c(360450,1690139,5420594,3060411,450341,5420324,730162),X3456Avgintensity=c(110.3703,469.5097,407.557,123.9965,2234.529,190.7429,110.072),X3456Pvalue=c(0.8424522,0.01054713,0.01450231,0.5800923,0,0.1437047,0.8477257))

file3=list(ProbeID=c(360450,1690139,5420594,3060411,450341,5420324,730162),X678Avgintensity=c(66.78696,160.4022,207.996,80.48443,1187.988,91.58123,85.80681),X678Pvalue=c(0.9538563,0.02768622,0.01450231,0.6031641,0,0.313118,0.444298))

file4=list(ProbeID=c(360450,1690139,5420594,3060411,450341,5420324,730162),X8701Avgintensity=c(83.57081,141.5529,238.9153,98.10896,1060.654,97.65002,83.88175),X8701Pvalue=c(0.814766,0.03493738,0.005273566,0.3651945,0,0.3750824,0.808174))
```

Comment: If you want your question answered, you need to provide a minimal, reproducible example.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/602276 and then try again.

Comment: I've made fairly heavy edits to your question. Would you double check them please.

Comment: What do you consider a "correct" value?

Comment: @Andrie Sorry for the inconvenience,I have read the minimal reproducible example,Next time I will follow that rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that 47,315 rows is particular large. So here is how I would do it:

1. Find a file that you are happy with that contains the correct number of rows. Read in this file and call is `f1`
2. Now loop through the remaining files and compare the probeID column with the correct column in `f1`. Make a note of the files that are valid. When looping through the files, here are a few tips:

   - Keep overwriting the comparison file, i.e. don't have data sets `f3`, `f4`, `f5`. At any one time you should just have `f1` and a single comparison data set. This will save memory.
   - In the `read.csv` function, look at the `colClasses` argument. Looking at your example data set, something like `colClasses=c("numeric", "numeric", "numeric")` should work. This will make it quicker when reading in data.

**Update**

Following the edit to your question, you seem to be interested in the number of lines a particular file has, so here is some pseudo-code to help you:

```
fnames = list.files()
no_of_lines = numeric(length(fnames))
for(i in seq_along(fnames) {
    d = read.delim(fnames[i])
    no_of_lines[i] = dim(d)[1]
}
```

You can then use `plot` or `table` on `no_of_lines`

Comment: Actually there is no definite correct number of rows.for an example IF I Select 5 files all the 5 files should contain 47294 rows,if one of them contains 47314 then it should be print that this particular file rows does not match with other.

Comment: :I have redited the question with minimal information R code for the better understanding..Plese do help me

Comment: @csgillespie-ur code works fine and it gives the number of lines in my file.I want to compare those values within that function so that if it matched it should print "matches" else("unmatch between file1 and file 2")..I tried by writing one function but it works partially correct(ie when an  file  with unequal number of lines among others comes in the middle of selected files(3rd file among 7 files selected),it prints that files have same number of lines(actually it is not) but when the same file is selected as first file then it shows files mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

Like Colin said, it doesn't sound like your data files are very big.  Use `system.time` or one of the profiling packages to see how long it takes to read in each file will `read.delim`.  If it really does take too long, then see this question for how to go faster.

[Quickly reading very large tables as dataframes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r/1728422)

Answer (score 0):

You read tab-delimited files with `read.delim()`, it is identical to `read.table()` and `read.csv()` except for the defaults, which are setup to take `\t` as the seperator.

For example,

```
my.data <- read.delim('c:/path/to/my/file.txt')
```

Once you have the data in, you can count the number of rows using

```
nrow(my.data)
```

If checking validity is simply checking that the number of rows is 47,234 then you could do something like this

```
if(nrow(my.data) == 47234L) {
  do.something()
} else {
  do.something.else()
}
```

You may, however, be wanting to check distinct ProbeIDs, so you could do this instead

```
length(unique(my.data$ProbeID)) == 47234L
```

But, if you need to check that a certain list of 47,234 ProbeIDs is present, you will have to have that list somewhere loaded or defined already to check against it.  See @csgillespie's answer because I think that is where he was going.

As for performance, if you can load it in Excel, you can load it in R faster.

Comment: :I have re-edited the my posy with minimal reproducible code so that it will make much easier in understanding my problem..please do help me